# Call addClass on element which has ng-class

Tags: angularjs

If I have an element which has `ng-class` attribute with some binding and I call addClass on that element will these two work fine together?

I mean that will class attribute of that element contain both classes (one added via addClass call and another from ng-class)

For example:

Here is the element:

```
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" 
     ng-class="[col.colIndex(), { 'position-relative': col.grouping && row.groupHeader }]"
     ng-bind="COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS"
     data-directive-that-calls-add-class>
```

Here is the directive that calls addClass (its link function):

```
link: (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes) => {
     element.addClass("disable-safari-tooltip");
```

Comment: yes it will contain both classes

Comment: simply do : `ng-Clas="{ odd: odd, even: even }"`

Comment: @Sravan and if ng-class binding evaluates that class should be removed, it will remove only that one which was added by ng-class right so the one added by addClass remains

Comment: angularjs doesn't have any addClass directive,where is that function from?

Comment: @jabko87,can you please elaborate and add some code

Comment: Instead of calling addClass(), keep the expression in ng-class and name your class accordingly. Ex: ng-class="{selectedHeader: key == selectedCol}"

Comment: @Sravan: code added

Comment: @anu: yes, that's the best obviously, but I need to integrate some other directives which do this call and no refactoring time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where both the classes will be added one through `ng-class` and other through a `directive`.

The `ng-class` makes background yellow and `directive` makes text green

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
.yellow{
background-color: yellow
}
.red{
color: green
}
</style>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div red ng-class=" { 'yellow': yellow}" >Test</div>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.yellow = true;
})
app.directive('red', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr, $timeout) {
        
            $element.addClass("red");
        }
    };
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**But, if the same css property needs to be changed, then the last added will take more priority, for example, check the class is changed after 2 seconds through a directive**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
.yellow{
background-color: yellow
}
.red{
color: green
}
.blue{
background-color: blue
}
</style>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div red ng-class=" { 'yellow': yellow}" >Test</div>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.yellow = true;
})
app.directive('red', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
        
            $element.addClass("red");
             $timeout(function () {
        $element.addClass("blue");
    }, 2000);
            
        }
    };
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[**Here is a demo URL**](https://plnkr.co/edit/pMKtI5whLSBHchSMMts2?p=preview)